# RavenDb JsonIgnore Attribute throws error when generating document key

Tags: ravendb

Im moving out from Guid to string (HiLo) keys which is suggested by RavenDb docs.
Some of my DomainEvents gets fired inside the constructor so the Id should be known before firing the event. When I was using Guid, I'll just create Guid.NewGuid() to generate Id. But for the HiLo provided by RavenDb, what I did was an extension method to generate keys for me and then pass to my Entity constructor as argument.

**RavenDb Version: RavenDb.Client 3.0.30000**

`Note that this is a copy-paste code I found on the internet :)`

```
public static class RavenDbExtensions
    {
        public static string GenerateIdFor<T>(this IDocumentSession session)
        {
            // We need the advanced session in order to ensure that the keys are generated in the correct database.
            // session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands is not sufficient.
            var advancedSession = session.Advanced as DocumentSession;
            if (advancedSession == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            // An entity instance is required to generate a key, but we only have a type.
            // In our case, the entities don't have public constructors so we must use reflection.
            var entity = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true);

            // Generate an ID using the commands and conventions from the current session
            return advancedSession.Conventions.GenerateDocumentKey(
                advancedSession.DocumentStore.Identifier,
                advancedSession.DatabaseCommands, 
                entity);
        }
    }
```

My controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("add", Name = "courses.add")]
        public ActionResult Add(AddViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.Categories = DocumentSession.Query<Category>().ToList();

                return View(model);
            }

            string courseId = DocumentSession.GenerateIdFor<Course>();
            var course = Course.Create(
                courseId,
                model.Title,
                CourseCode.FromString(model.Code),
                StandardDuration.Create(model.Days, model.HoursPerDay),
                model.StandardPrice,
                model.CategoryId);

            DocumentSession.Store(course);

            return RedirectToAction("Add");
        }
```

I have this class with JsonIgnore `(Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json)` attribute

```
public class StandardDuration : ValueObject
    {
        private StandardDuration(int days, int hoursPerDay)
        {
            Days = days;
            HoursPerDay = hoursPerDay;
        }

        public int Days { get; private set; }
        public int HoursPerDay { get; private set; }

        public static StandardDuration Create(int days, int hoursPerDay)
        {
            if (days <= 0)
                throw new DomainModelException("Days should be atleast one");

            if (hoursPerDay <= 0)
                throw new DomainModelException("CreditHours should be greater than zero");

            return new StandardDuration(days, hoursPerDay);
        }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public int CreditHours
        {
            get { return HoursPerDay * Days; }
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
        {
            yield return Days;
            yield return HoursPerDay;
        }
    }
```

which throws an error

`Attempt by method 'Raven.Client.Document.DocumentConvention.DefaultTypeTagName(System.Type)' to access method 'Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.TypeExtensions.IsGenericType(System.Type)' failed.`

[image]

**UPDATE**

I cant reproduce the error on the code above due to same issue but before showing the page.

But Im facing the same issue even on `non JsonIgnore decorated` classes.

```
public class Category : Entity
    {
        private Category() { }

        private Category(Guid id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public static Category Create(Guid id, string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                throw new DomainModelException("Category name should not be blank or null.");

            return new Category(id, name);
        }
    }
```

**controller action**

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("add", Name = "course_categories.add")]
        public ActionResult Add(string name)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var courseCategory = Category.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), name);
                DocumentSession.Store(courseCategory);

                AddSuccessMessage("Course Category created");

                return RedirectToRoute("course_categories.add_page");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "An error occurred please try again.");

            return View();
        }
```

[image]

**stack trace:**

```
[MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Raven.Client.Document.DocumentConvention.DefaultTypeTagName(System.Type)' to access method 'Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.TypeExtensions.IsGenericType(System.Type)' failed.]
   Raven.Client.Document.DocumentConvention.DefaultTypeTagName(Type t) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentConvention.cs:264
   Raven.Client.Document.DocumentConvention.GetTypeTagName(Type type) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentConvention.cs:296
   Raven.Client.Document.DocumentConvention.DefaultFindFullDocumentKeyFromNonStringIdentifier(Object id, Type type, Boolean allowNull) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentConvention.cs:152
   Raven.Client.Document.GenerateEntityIdOnTheClient.GetIdAsString(Object entity, Object value, String& id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\GenerateEntityIdOnTheClient.cs:49
   Raven.Client.Document.GenerateEntityIdOnTheClient.TryGetIdFromInstance(Object entity, String& id) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\GenerateEntityIdOnTheClient.cs:33
   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.Store(Object entity) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:646
   Web.Features.CourseCategories.CourseCategoriesController.Add(String name) in E:\Projects\Akademia\Presentation\Web\Features\CourseCategories\CourseCategoriesController.cs:39
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9721605
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: what is the full stack?

Comment: sorry for the late response. please see my update

Comment: It looks like you have mismatch versions of the dlls here.

Comment: yeah I guess. Thank you I really appreciate your support on your product